# Troubleshooting ECDSA implementation in rust

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, signature, secp256k1

I'm trying to implement ECDSA for learning purposes and have generated public and private keys, which seem to be correct as I have compared them with those generated by an online tool called [noble](https://paulmillr.com/noble/). However, my signing or verification algorithm (or both) is not working correctly and I am having difficulty debugging the code due to my lack of cryptographic or mathematical background. I have been trying to fix the issue for the past two days with no luck any second eye would really be appreciated.
If there are any important details that I have missed in this description, please let me know and I will modify the post.

Btw I'm implementing The algorithms based on [cryptobook nakov](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-messages)

this is my signing algorithm:

```
    // FieldElement struct is just num % prime
 pub fn sign(&self, z: FieldElement) -> Signature {
        // this struct contains all secp256k1 parameters
        let params = Secp256k1Param::new();
        // get a random 1 < k < n - 1
        let k = BigInt::from(get_rndm(&params.n()));
        // wrape it in a FieldElement to be able to multiply it with the generator
        // k % prime
        let k = FieldElement {
            num: k,
            prime: params.prime(),
        };
        // r = k * G
        let r = params.generator().multiply(&k);
        // k_inv = k^-1 = k^(n-2) mod n
        let k_inv = k.num().modpow(&(params.n().sub(2)), &params.n());
        // s = k^-1 * (z + r * d) mod n
        let s = (k_inv * (&z.num + (&r.x.num() * &self.prk))) % &params.n();
        // wrap s in a FieldElement
        let s = FieldElement {
            num: s,
            prime: params.prime(),
        };

        // signature is struct {r, s} where r is an EllipticPoint and s is a FieldElement
        // EllipticPoint {x, y, a, b}
        // FieldElement {num, prime}
        let sign = Signature { r, s };
        sign
```

and this is my verification algorithm:

```
    pub fn verify(&self, z: FieldElement, signature: Signature) -> bool {
        let params = Secp256k1Param::new();
        // calculating the hash of the message h = hash(z)
        let h = hash(&z.num().to_string(), None).num();
        // r' = (h * s^-1) * G + (r * s^-1 * pk)
        // (h * s^-1) * G  (I'm sure that multiplication method in EllipticPoint is correct since i used it in Public/private key generation and they're correct)
        let left_side =  params.generator().multiply(&FieldElement::new(h * &signature.s.num().modpow(&(params.n().sub(2)), &params.n()), params.prime()));
        // (r * s^-1 * pk)
        let right_side = signature.r.multiply(&FieldElement::new(signature.s.num().modpow(&(params.n().sub(2)), &params.n()) * &self.pk(), params.prime()));
        // r' = (h * s^-1) * G + (r * s^-1 * pk)
        let r2 = left_side.add(&right_side);
        // equality of two elliptic points is the equality of their x,y,a,b coordinates
        r2.eq(&signature.r)
    }
```

my tests are simply:

```
  let params = Secp256k1Param::new();
    let keys = ECDSA::new("my secret key".to_string());
    println!("private key: {}", keys.prk());
    println!("public key: {}", keys.pk());
    //
    let msg = "hello world";
    let msg_hash = hash(msg, None);
    println!("message hash: {}", msg_hash.num().to_str_radix(16));
    
    let signature = keys.sign(msg_hash.clone());
    if keys.verify(msg_hash, signature) == true {
        println!("signature is valid");
    } else {
        // println!("s: {}", signature.s.num().to_str_radix(16));
        println!("signature is invalid");
    }
```

Comment: There is no reason for $k$ to be viewed as an element of field $\mathbb F_p$. It's more useful to view it as an element of field $\mathbb F_n$, but neither allows "to multiply it with the generator". Same for $s$. The $r$ of your signature is $kG$, it should be the X coordinate of $kG$ reduced modulo $n$ (your linked reference forgets that reduction; it's NOT what causes the issue). Hashing is part of signing. I suggest using [this](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) as true reference for ECDSA, and [this](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1) for secp256k1